# Best way to send() optional parameter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method which accepts two parameters. One of them is optional. These params are actually names of methods which should be send to an object. How to avoid getting `NoMethodError` if the second parameter is missed without using condition? Can I send some "empty" method which doesn't do anything? In my case this works fine, but it doesn't look good. Thanks.

```
def foo param_1, parm_2='to_s'
  object.public_send(param_1).public_send(param_2)
end
```

**UPD**
send is changed to public_send thanks to @Surya

Comment: Where do you call this method? What does it look like?

Comment: Is `foo` expected to return a specific value?

Comment: And do you want to send `param_2` to `object` or to the return value of `object.send(param_1)`?

Comment: And why do you want to avoid a condition in the first place? Just to save a line of code?

Comment: I'm OK with condition. I was just curious about this way to define a method. I want to send param_2 to the result of `object.send(param_1)`

Comment: I think @Jack Noble answer with :itself is pretty much what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Ruby 2.2.0 or later you can call `#itself` on any object and get that object. So in your example you can do

```
def foo param_1, param_2 = :itself
 object.send(param_1).send(param_2)
end
```

And it will be the same as

```
def foo param_1, param_2 = nil
  thing = object.send(param_1)
  if param_2
    thing.send(param_2)
  else
    thing
  end
end
```

I also second Surya's advice to always use `#public_send` instead.

Comment: Seems like nice solution so far

Comment: I like the `itself` idea.

But using `send` seems like a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send) like so:

```
object.send(:my_method, param_1, param_2)
```

Where `my_method` is the method name defined for `object`. I would encourage you to use [`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send) instead, as `send` enables your code to call private methods, which may result in unexpected behavior of your application.

You can quickly check if param_2 is available or not:

```
value = param_2.nil? ? object.send(param_1.to_sym) : object.send(param_1.to_sym).send(param_2.to_sym)
```

Comment: In my case param_1 and param_2 are methods names which should be called on object, not :my_method's params.
Thanks for public_send. I'll use it instead.